# SQL - Grouping column based on another column, with max 100 rows per entry

Tags: sql, ssms, aggregate-functions

I've been tasked with grouping a column codes with unittype, problem is that there's more than a thousand entries for each unit type, so when attempting the following, it gives me an error of too many entries exceeded the limit of 8k bytes (using SSMS). I'd also like to group these entries by 100.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbr5s.png)

| unitType | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 100Kilograms | J90 |
| Kilogram | A701, Y02 |
| Kilogram | AY08,R809,LY10, AY11, UY12 |
| No Unit | OP14M DY16 |

When running a standard piece of code such as

```
SELECT [UnitType],
       CONCAT('[',STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"',Code,'"'),','),']') AS Codes
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY [UnitType]
```

It gives me:

> STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

The ideal solution is to group them by hundreds, shown by the example above. For example if there's 250 codes for 100 kilograms, I'd like there to be 3 entries with 100 codes for the first two rows and 50 for the last row. This is quite important for the next stage. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to enumerate the records and group them by batches of 100:

```
SELECT [UnitType],
       CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', Code, '"'), ', ') ,']') AS Codes
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [UnitType] ORDER BY [id]) rn
    FROM [Table] t
) t
GROUP BY [UnitType], (rn -1) / 100
```

I assumed that a column called `id` can be used to order the records; you might need to adapt this the actual structure of your table.

Comment: Can you explain what the t.* an d the ts are? Sorry I'm a little new to this

Comment: @Locusflow: `t` is just an alias for the table (or later on for the subquery). So `t.*` means "all columns of the table".

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to build groups of 100 codes:

```
SELECT 
  [UnitType],
  CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', code, '"'), ','), ']') AS codes
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    [UnitType],
    code,
    FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code) - 1) / 100) AS code_group
  FROM [Table]
) with_code_group
GROUP BY [UnitType], code_group
ORDER BY [UnitType], code_group;
```

Invoking `FLOOR` may be superfluous here, because `ROW_NUMBER` probably results in an INT, so `/` would become an integer division where 50 / 100 = 0, not 0.5. But, well, I don't like guessing, and `FLOOR` makes the operation explicit.

Comment: Oops, seems I am a tad late with my answer :-) It doesn't add anything to GMB's answer. I didn't see their answer when posting mine.